# On maximal Cohen-Macaulay property of a special kind of ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a local Cohen-Macaulay domain of dimension at least $2$. Let $M$ be a maximal Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module such that localization of $M$ at every height $1$ prime ideal of $R$ is free. Consider a short exact sequence $0\to F \to M \to I \to 0$ where $F$ is a free $R$-module and $I$ is a non-zero ideal of $R$ such that localisation of $I$ at every height $1$ prime ideal of $R$ is free. Then, is $I$ a maximal Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module?

By depth along short exact sequence (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00LX),
clearly $\text{depth } I \ge \dim R -1$, but I cannot decide if $\text{depth } I = \dim R$ or not.

Please help.

Comment: Let $R=k[[x,y]]$ and $M=R^2$, a free module of rank two. Then you have a surjection from $M$ to the maximal ideal and its kernel is free. But the maximal ideal is not maximal Cohen- Macaulay.

Comment: @Mohan: Thank you.